# A ball released is released from a height “h” it touches the ground and bounces to a higher surface

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work, potential-energy

So the ball bounces and to a higher surface which has a height equal to h/2 it’s potential energy would be equal to mgh/2 with respect to the higher surface my question is , what happens to the “extra energy” it previously had would it get converted to heat/sound energy or something else ?

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned that it rebounds only to a height of $\frac{h}{2}$ , this means that the collision between the ball and the ground was [**inelastic**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inelastic_collision) which means  that some of the energy is lost either in deforming the ball or heat or sound.

Had the collision been perfectly elastic
there would have been no loss of energy and the ball rebounds to the same initial height.

Hope it helps .

Comment: @KRATOS0990 was that helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

Some energy is lost through the viscosity of the medium the ball passes through.Assuming it is air then the energy loss would be small.The impact would take care of any other energy lost